# Segmentation Fault on deluged

Tags: raspbian, deluge

Hi I recently setup my raspberry pi as a torrent-box following [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/142044/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-an-always-on-bittorrent-box/).

I tried running deluged in logging to console mode
`deluged -d -L debug`

However, the only message I get before it stops is `Segmentation Fault`

How do you fix this?

Comment: Hi @Butters I bumped removed all other connections that use power, I also did an `rpi-update` deluged seems to crash the entire system after a longer time.

Answer (score 3):

Seg fault == a bug in `deluged` or something to which it is linked.  You should report that first to debian:

http://www.debian.org/Bugs/

Make sure you mention you are using raspbian and explain exactly what happens, including a cut and paste of the output leading up to that point.  It will be particularly helpful if you also install `gdb` (the "gnu debugger"):

```
> sudo apt-get install gdb
```

Then run deluged inside of it:

```
> gdb deluged
```

No options or arguments; a copyright paragraph will appear followed by a prompt, `(gdb)`.  You type:

```
(gdb) run -d -L debug
```

The runtime parameters you used.  The seg fault should happen again and gdb will catch it and ask you what you want to do.  Then:

```
(gdb) bt
```

This will print a "backtrace".  If it asks you to install "debug-infos" (it probably will), do that and repeat the process until it doesn't ask again (to quit gdb each time, use `quit` and say `y`).  At that point, copy paste the backtrace and include it in your bug report.

You can copy paste with the mouse in console mode if you install and run `gpm` (the "general purpose mouse" daemon) but probably this will be easiest in a GUI terminal.